# Azure website - Attach storage (blob) and ftp to that storage

Tags: asp.net, azure, ftp, azure-storage, azure-web-roles

I am using Azure to host my asp.net website as WebSite which allows user to fetch files. There is a limit of 1 GB on the website so I have to attach storage to that website.

My problem is that I want to hook that storage with WebSite and pragmatically fetch files stored there.

Secondly, there is another website which will put the resources inside that blob . For faster access, I want to use ftp to do that. Blob does not allow ftp directly for the containers.

For attaching blob, I found a [link](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs-20/) from Azure that can be used but would not mind if there is a better approach for doing this.

I have the custom [FTP code](http://geekswithblogs.net/jkrebsbach/archive/2013/09/19/options-for-azure-blob-storage.aspx) but the concern is why does azure not allow storage to be exposed using ftp and secondly, would there be much of difference in using this ftp and uploading file using rest it exposes?

Comment: I haven't found a better way than using the API in that link.

Answer (score 0):

> For attaching blob, I found a link from Azure that can be used but
>   would not mind if there is a better approach for doing this.

From a web perspective, That's a better approach, I mean using SDK. Other option what you have is to directly make REST API calls to Blob Storage. In fact even SDK makes REST API calls behind the scenes. Even if you use PowerShell to make operation on Blob Storage, all the underlying calls would be REST calls.

> For faster access, I want to use ftp to do that. Blob does not allow
>   ftp directly for the containers.

You can use this codeplex project and set up FTP for Azure Blob - http://geekswithblogs.net/jkrebsbach/archive/2013/09/19/options-for-azure-blob-storage.aspx. It needs to be deployed in Worked Role.

Comment: I have that FTP code but the concern is why does azure not allow storage to be exposed using ftp and secondly, would there be much of difference in using this ftp and uploading file using rest it exposes?

Comment: @Ankit One immediate reason I can think of for Azure not having FTP support for storage is its structure and strategy in maintaining data in different partitions and on different physical boxes, though I am not sure about exact reason. For your second question, there is a difference with this FTP and normal REST API calls. Even this FTP approach uses REST calls underlying to get the data. So that adds performance impact. Its always good to use REST API directly.